# How does WPF receive touch input?

Tags: c#, wpf, windows-7, touch, windows-messages

I am working with WPF (C#, Windows 7, .NET 4.0) and its touch events. A question that came to my mind while doing this is, how does wpf exactly get the touch input? In the msdn articel [Architectural Overview](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/dd371413%28VS.85%29.aspx) it is said that the 'application' gets the input through WM_TOUCH messages, but i couldn't find information on how old that article is (and therefore if it is applicable to WPF). Also I read (for example [here](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/279c2d4e-1180-4c64-ae01-c9e7a4366b24/how-to-handle-wndproc-messages-wmgesture-in-wpf?forum=wpf)) that you can't recieve gesture messages in a WPF application.

So, does WPF convert the touch messages internally and then presents them to the programmer through touch events like 'TouchDown'? Why can't you access the messagese if it is so? Is there an official source that explicitly states how WPF receives touch input?

Comment: Take a look at the [Touch and Manipulation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms754010.aspx#touch_and_manipulation) section in the [Input Overview](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms754010.aspx) article on MSDN.

Comment: @Clemens Maybe I wasn't clear enough in my question, I want to know how a WPF element gets the information that it has to throw an event. In the article that you linked it is only explained what happens if a WPF element throws an event and how to react to it. If I didn't understand the article correctly and it does in fact answer my question, please be a bit more specific where the information is "hidden". :)

Answer (score 0):

WPF uses the older Windows <=7 compatible `WM_LBUTTONDOWN`, `WM_MOUSEMOVE`, etc., rather than the modern `WM_POINTER` events or gestures. It also does not use `WM_TOUCH` or `WM_GESTURE`. See the relevant source code [here](https://github.com/dotnet/wpf/blob/main/src/Microsoft.DotNet.Wpf/src/PresentationCore/System/Windows/InterOp/HwndMouseInputProvider.cs#L383) and in particular the comment about `WM_POINTERxxx` messages. I'm not sure why the MSDN article appears to contradict this, but the source code don't lie. Sadly the contemplated support for modern pointer events and in particular OS-enabled gestures was never added.

Nonetheless, WPF actually is flexible enough to be used with Windows 8+ pointer events and gestures, if you or any other reader is interested and willing to get deep into the weeds. This is done through [Interaction Context](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/_input_intcontext/) and handling native Windows touch events with a substitute `WndProc`, bypassing WPF's built-in handling. When I needed to add touch support to my WPF application, I found this was the only way to get a satisfactory result.

There's an [old CodeProject article](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/607234/Using-Windows-8-Interaction-Con) that goes into good detail and has all the scaffolding for using Interaction Context from C# generally, though the example is only for WinForms.

Adapting it to WPF is not trivial and beyond what can be communicated in one SO answer, but the gist of it is:

- Get an `HwndSource` for your main window using `PresentationSource.FromVisual`
- Register a custom `WndProc` using `HwndSource.AddHook`
- Register the window as a gesture-enabled window using the Win32 API `RegisterTouchWindow` (see the CodeProject article)
- In your `WndProc`, handle `WM_POINTERDOWN`, `WM_POINTERUP`, `WM_POINTERUPDATE`, and `WM_POINTERCAPTURECHANGED`, otherwise return `IntPtr.Zero`.

Then use Interaction Context as outlined in the CodeProject article. Without rehashing the article completely, any potential recipient of a gesture event (i.e. a `FrameworkElement` etc.), needs to register a callback and get an "interaction context" which is just an `IntPtr`. Then in `WndProc`, whenever you handle a pointer event you need to identify the target of the pointer contact using [VisualTreeHelper.HitTest](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.media.visualtreehelper.hittest?view=windowsdesktop-8.0). Once you identify the target, and if you see that it's registered as accepting touch gestures (all of which you need to track yourself), you then call additional Win32 APIs providing the low-level pointer info from the message along with the interaction context identifying the visual target. Eventually, only once enough input is received or sufficient time has passed for a touch to register as a gesture, etc., Windows will execute a callback with the actual high-level gesture - tap, manipulation, etc.

This way you can get a WPF application to respond to touch precisely the same way a UWP or WinUI app does, with exactly the same feel. This is impossible with WPF's built in touch support (if it can even be called that).

I remember a WPF sample out there somewhere that made use of the linked CP article as a base, but I cannot find it. If anyone is aware of one please post in the comments or feel free to make the edit.

Answer (score -1):

I believe what you are talking about is more of "physics" of the touch device. 
How does WPF receive the input from touch screen?

Touch screen is like any other input devices like mouse or keyboard. The way it works is by finger pressure, of course. The chip inside the touch device figures out the bounds , areas , co-ordinates of the finger you are pressing.This will then be translated by operating system to the appropriate events or messages, just like key-board or mouse. Hence, message is not specific to `WPF`. All other applications listen to the same "kind" of message from operating system to receive the `touch` input in the form of "message" or "event" based on the hardware and operating system.

If you really want to know how does WPF receive the input, you could use the excellent [ILSpy](http://ilspy.net/) tool and dig deeper into System.Windows.Input.Touch class

You could see more information [here](http://www.explainthatstuff.com/touchscreens.html) on the mechanism of touch-screen.

On a side note, unlike mouse input, which is single-point, touch is multi-point. And WPF raises events like `TouchEnter` , `TouchLeave`, `TouchMove`, `TouchUp`, `TouchDown` and so on and `TouchEventArgs` gives you the information on position and bounds of the touch.

Comment: Well, not exactly. I want to know if WPF uses the same Messages (WM_TOUCH and WM_GESTURE), that you can use in Winforms (through Pinvoke). You seem to suggest that it does, but I would like to have some msdn page or something else that clearly states this as fact.

Comment: what you are asking is pretty low level and not openly discussed by Microsoft, however you could see this article on windows touch application. [https://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/comparing-touch-coding-techniques-windows-8-desktop-touch-sample] . The windows app invokes the low level API call basically using these three set of messages; WM_POINTER, WM_TOUCH and WM_GESTURE. Since WPF only works in Windows OS and requires full .net framework, I'm pretty sure it must also going the same route and making those call under the hood.

Comment: Notice that WM_POINTER only works in windows 8 and since WPF works in both windows 7 and 8. WPF must only be using WM_TOUCH and WM_GESTURE.

Comment: That's kinda the problem. This is all pretty vague and I wanted a definitive answer. But thanks for your time nonetheless!

Comment: No worries . I will let you know if I come across something definite.

Comment: Just a friendly aside, the source code for WPF is now on Github, and actually was published long ago under a restricted "research only" type license. When in doubt, go to the source!